# .NET web-based object browser/inspector

Tags: c#, debugging, inspector

I have a rather sophisticated caching system in place for a web application.  I would like to expose, through the management console of the application, a viewer for the cached objects.

Essentially, I'm looking for something like the Visual Studio object inspector that's available whilst debugging.

I certainly can write something, and in fact, I have a working prototype that uses a tree control.  I'm looking for something a bit more sophisticated that I don't have to maintain :)[image: Sample Debug View]

Answer (score 0):

This [blogpost](http://community.sharpdevelop.net/blogs/mattward/archive/2006/05/21/ComponentInspector.aspx) might give you a hint on the *.NET Component Inspector* from Oakland software and a software called *Reflector* that might suit you needs.